# convergence of a sequence at finite n

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have an infinite sequence with $a_1=c>0$ and $a_n=[a_{n-1}-b]^+$ where $[\,]^+$ is equal to zero if the value inside $[\,]$ is negative and b can be any positive value. Apparently, this sequence is convergent to zero. And I would like to know whether the sequence can converge at finite n when b is a positive value which is extremely close to zero. Thank you!

Comment: What is the power? It seems that you've written

$$a_n={\left(a_{n-1}-b\right)}^+$$

Comment: yes, exactly as you have written. Appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks~

Comment: Just replaced ` with `$`!

Comment: thanks for the edits! I will appreciate if you have a comment on my question.

Comment: Isn't it trivial? We have a(n) = c - n b as long as c>n b and a(n) = 0 for all n with c<n b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will always converge in finite time. If $b=0$, then $a_n$ is constant. If $b>0$, then $$a_n=\max \{c-(n-1)b,0\},$$ so that $a_n=0$ for all $n$ with $c-(n-1)b\leq 0$, that is, $n\geq \frac{c}b +1$.

Comment: thanks. My concern is whether $\frac{c}{b}$ is equal to infinity if $b$ is extremely small like infinitesimal. But I may get confused with a small real value extremely close to zero with infinitesimal which in many cases is not considered as a real number. Any comment on this?

Comment: No, if $b>0$ then $\frac{c}{b}$ is always a well defined number (and if additionally $c>0$, then it is a *positive* number). Infinity is not a number, no real number can be equal to infinity.

Comment: got it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If $a_0>0$ then you can verify that
$$\begin{align}a_1&=a_0-1\times b\\a_j&=a_0-j\times b\end{align}$$
as long as $jb<a_0$. And if $b>0$ then there is $n$ such that $nb>a_0$ i.e. just set:
$$n=\lfloor\frac{a_0}b\rfloor+1$$
So that $a_0-nb<0$ and $\{a_n\}$ is always convergent in finite time.

Comment: like my comment to the first answer, my real concern is whether $\frac{c}{b}$ can be equal to infinity if $b$ is approaching to zero. Could you please comment on my concern? Thanks!

Comment: If $b=0$ the sequence is constant. if $b$ is near zero , $m$ will be great.

Comment: @Tough_Man As $b$ approaches to zero, $c/b$ would **approach** to infinity. Approaching infinity is something and being $\infty$ is a completely other thing. As long as $b$ is not _equal_ to zero, the series converge in finite time

Comment: @polfosol, thanks! I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $b>0$.
Let $m\geq 0$ such that
$$mb\leq c<(m+1)b.$$
then
$$a_2=c-b,$$

$$0\leq a_{m+1}=c-mb<b,$$
and $$a_{m+2}=a_{m+3}=...=0.$$

with $m=\lfloor \frac{c}{b} \rfloor$.

For $n> m+1  \;\; a_n=0=\lim_{n\to+\infty }a_n$.

Comment: like my comments to the previous answers, my real concern is whether $\frac{c}{b}$ can be equal to infinity if $b$ is approaching to zero. Could you please comment on my concern? Thanks!